# axios.get is not returning anything in nodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a problem with .get request.
Somehow it is not returning anything?
Any suggestions?

```
GET http://localhost:8080/admin net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Get Route,With this I'm trying to filter all items by their username:

```
   app.get("/:username", verify, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Welcome to roffys server");
  Todo.find({ username: req.params.username }).then((err, todo) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error retrieving todos");
    } else {
      res.json(todo);
    }
  });
});
```

Verify function,here I'm verifying my auth-token,I console logged it and it is working fine:

```
    const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header("auth-token");
  console.log("-----token", token);
  if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access Denied");
  try {
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, "secretkey");
    req.user = verified;
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send("Invalid token");
    next();
  }
};
```

FE Side with ReactJS :

```
 componentDidMount() {
const { getAll, setPageCount } = this.props.actions;
axios
  .get(`http://localhost:8080/${localStorage.getItem("username")}`, {
    headers: {
      "auth-token": localStorage.getItem("auth-token"),
    },
  })
  .then((res) => {
    getAll(res.data);
    setPageCount();
    console.log("--------res.data", res.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("err", err);
  });
  }
```

Comment: You can't use route parameter with an empty path like that because Express will treat it as a route path. Try `app.get("/user/:username"` and adjust your api call

Comment: I did it and it is still giving me 404

Answer (score 1):

You're not responding or calling `next` in your auth middleware. Add the `next()` to the middleware so that the req goes to the next middleware or respond there only.

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header("auth-token");
  console.log("-----token", token);
  if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access Denied");
  try {
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, "secretkey");
    req.user = verified;

    //call next or respond
    next()

  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send("Invalid token");
    next();
  }
};
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I've putted next in my get route too but it is still giving me error 404

Comment: @Roffybc You've not added it in the middleware where you're logging the token in the `try` block. The `req` will keep hanging there.

Comment: Now it cant find user and is giving me error on that

Comment: @Roffybc that might be related to the code you wrote for the users.But it does return an error now.

Comment: Yep thats a progress

Comment: It is giving me error at Verify function : const token = req.header("auth-token");  <- do you know how to fix it ?